# Two- Sample T test on Employment Data

Tags: r, regression, self-study, t-test, econometrics

I'm trying to conduct a two sample t-test on [this data](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SMU53426607072200001SA) on food and drink workers in the Seattle MSA to see if there is a mean difference in levels of employment before and after the enactment of an increase in the minimum wage after April 1, 2015. The background for this project is that many people say that an increase in the minimum wage will force low-skill employers to cut their staff in order to minimize costs.

I've included my code below but some have indicated that my statistics aren't correct. Is there a better way of doing this with a t-test? How could I do a regression analysis on this same data? Would I have to create a new variable with the minimum wage for each corresponding observation date?

The data into two variables (observations before and after the minimum wage increase took effect),.

```
#seattleData <- read.table(file=file.choose(), 2 # header=T, sep=",",)
 food_drink_workers <- seattleData$food_drink_workers
 afterMinWageLaw <- food_drink_workers[304:346]
 beforeMinWageLaw <- food_drink_workers[1:303]
 boxplot(beforeMinWageLaw, afterMinWageLaw)
 options(scipen = 100)
 t.test(beforeMinWageLaw, afterMinWageLaw, mu=0, 
 alternative "less", conf=.95, 
 var.equal = FALSE, paired = FALSE)
```

Results:

```
Welch Two Sample t-test 
data: beforeMinWageLaw and afterMinWageLaw 
t = -36.92, df = 160.8, p-value < 0.00000000000000022 
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval: 
-Inf -38.87279 
sample estimates: 
mean of x mean of y 
103.8059 144.5023
```

Comment: @12b345b6b78: When the question asker posts an image of code instead of copy/pasting it as text, it's better to request the question asker edit their post. This will avoid possible transcription errors, and inform a new user of the posting etiquette here on SO.

Comment: will keep in mind!

Comment: I've added the code as text rather than a picture. Sorry I'm still new to the site

Comment: Also, when I do the t-test paired it gives me the same p-value.

Comment: Could I do that using the same data with a different code?

Comment: Regardless of the correctness of your calculations or choice of procedure, the results tell you nothing at all about the question of interest.  It is obvious from a plot of the data that the total employment of these workers has been rising from 2010 through 2018. You have no basis to attribute that to a change in minimum wage in 2015, because so many other variables were simultaneously affecting employment.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But what I'm asking is what kind of (relatively simple) regression model could I use to conduct a more robust and better fitting test. We haven't studied time series analysis in the class I'm doing this for hence why I'm not using something more complicated like an ARIMA model. We're only supposed to use the more basic statistics.

Comment: Please (1) apply the [tag:self-study] tag to your question and (2) ask for something more focused and explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The p-value is correct, the error lies in your method. If we plot the time series I think this will become obvious.

```
# Data  
employees <- read.csv("https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?id=SMU53426607072200001SA", 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Plot time series
employees[,1] <- as.Date(employees[,1])

plot(employees, type="l")
abline(v=as.Date("2015-04-01"), col="blue")
```

[image]

As you can see, it should be no surprise that the p-value is very small. Try and imagine how the black line would have to look for the p-value to be ~1.
As for paired vs. unpaired. A paired test only works when the two samples you compare are of the same size (for it to be possible to "pair them up").

Comment: This is helpful. So how could I do a regression analysis on this same data? Would I have to create a new variable with the minimum wage for each corresponding observation date?